# Graphic representation of changing temperatures

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to program a matlab code in R2012a that will allow a color representation of temperature change on a surface based on different corresponding height and temperature measurements. Then end goal would be to combine multiple images together to get some sort of a jpeg. The temperatures I recorded were time specific which is why it would be beneficial in the end to have a visual depicting this temperature change over time.

It has been a little bit of time since I have used matlab, and I have never created something This complicated. It has me a little over whelmed and wondering where to start.

Thanks for any and all advice!

Comment: Your question is quite unclear to me. Do you want some sort of movie that shows how the temperature varies over time? From your question you seem to have 4 variables - time, height, and x and y position on the surface?

Comment: A movie would be great, I just don't really know where to start on this. The x position on the surface is not important for this particular scenario because it is a uniform temperature at each of the given heights.

Comment: I personally feel this is too broad and quite unclear.  x doesn't matter - but y and z (height) do?  Is it a fixed surface (which happens to have varying heights across it) or do the height and temperature both vary with time?  Give us an image, some sample data, some code, *something*, otherwise it's just guessing which of the many ways of plotting 4D data is going to work with what you're trying to do.  (If you can't post images directly, link to an external source and ask for it to be edited in).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the `avifile` [documentation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/avifile.html) for details on how to create a movie from a series of frames, there is a nice example that should make it clear enough.

Now to generate the frames needed for the avi file. Here, the `meshgrid` and `surf` functions come in handy. `meshgrid` generates two coordinate matrices with x and y coordinates for every point on your plate, `surf` then allows you to plot a surface with colors given by the temperatures at these positions. For example:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:5,1:10)  % generate a 10*5 plate with step size 1
z = rand(10,5)              % height of the plate for a given position
c = rand(10,5)              % color values, these should be your (time-dependent) temperatures 

surf(x,y,z,c)
```

It is not clear to me whether you actually have a curved surface (requiring three coordinates to define each position), or just a simple plate. If it is just a simple plate, you can just set `z = ones(size(x))` to obtain an uniform height.